# Product of $i^4+4$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

The following is the Problem $50$ (Folklore) from [this pdf](https://www.nicecontest.xyz/static/media/NJ1.655ca2cf.pdf):

> Determine all positive integers $k$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^k (i^4+4)$ is a perfect square.

I realised that $i^4+4$ is just the Sophie-Germain identity, so the problem resolves to proving $2(k^2+2k+2)(k^2+1)$ is square, and I realised $(k^2+2k+2)(k^2+1)=(k^2+k+1)^2+1,$ so we want to prove $(k^2+k+1)^2+1=2n^2$ (because if $2x$ is a perfect square, $x$ is $n^2$). This makes me think of the Pell equation, but it seems to be too complicated.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the question in full in your post. Don't make others click external links (and it's especially bad in this case as one has to hunt for the right problem).

Comment: Alright, I just edited it.

Comment: Hint: gcd of $k^2+1$ and $k^2+2k+2$ divides 5.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the Sophie-Germain identity", nor why the problem reduces to proving $2(k^2+2k+2)(k^2+1)$ is a square (which it usually isn't).

Comment: $k = 2$ is a solution. Beyond that, there dont seem be to any. But I dont have a proof.

Comment: @GerryMyerson At least in the contest-math scene Sophie Germain -identity is the factorization
$$x^4+4=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2).$$ It plays a role in many a fun problem. If we write $p(x)=x^2-2x+2$, the other factor is $p(x+2)$. This implies that the factors in this product pair up nicely with the exceptions of $p(2)=2$, $p(k+1)$ and $p(k+2)$. Or were you simply protesting about the hyphen and I'm being dense :-)

Comment: @GerryMyerson FYI, the [Sophie Germain identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sophie-germain-identity) is that $a^4+4b^4=((a+b)^2+b^2)((a-b)^2+b^2)$. Using $a=i$ and $b=1$ gives $i^4+4=((i+1)^2+1)((i-1)^2+1)$. In the product, there's a telescoping type effect, with all $j^2+1$ type factors, for $0 \le j \le k+1$, having $2$ each matching up to form squares except for the first $2$, i.e., $0^2+1=1$ and $1^2+1=2$, plus the last $2$, i.e., $k^2+1$ and $(k+1)^2+1$. Thus, the product of these remaining factors must be a perfect square, i.e., the $2(k^2+2k+2)(k^2+1)$ the OP mentioned.

Comment: @Jyrki, no density on your part, I was protesting all the missing steps in the argument.

Comment: @John, thanks for filling in what OP left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this question requires to find all integers $k$ satisfying the statement than proving that statement is true ($k=1$ is false since it evaluates to 5)

So we can start from $2(k^2+1)(k^2+2k+2)$ which you found. For perfect squares we need two factors of the number to be equal:

$2(k^2+1)=k^2+2k+2_{---(1)}\\OR\\2(k^2+2k+2)=k^2+1_{---(2)}\\OR\\(k^2+1)(k^2+2k+2)=2_{---(3)}$

Solving $(1)$, we get $k=2 \: or \: 0$

Solving $(2)$, we get $k=-3 \: or \: -1$

Solving $(3)$, we get $k=0 \: or \: -1$

We can reject the solutions 0, -1 and -3 since $k\geqslant1$, therefore the only answer is 2.

Edit: Still figuring out how to find the integers k for non-equal factors like $2\times8=4^2$

For others who don't know how to find $2(k^2+1)(k^2+2k+2)$

$i^4 + 4\\= i^4 + 4i^2 + 4 - 4i^2\\=(i^2+2)^2-(2i)^2\\=(i^2+2i+2)(i^2-2i+2)\\=[(i+1)^2+1][(i-1)^2+1]$

So the question resolves to finding integers k making $\prod_{i=1}^{k}[(i+1)^2+1][(i-1)^2+1]$ a perfect square

Observe that for the graphs $L_1:y=(x+1)^2+1$ and $L_2:y=(x-1)^2+1$, $L_1$ is just 2 units on the left of $L_2$ which means substituting some n+2 into $L_2$ gives the same result as substituting n into $L_1$

Then we can get back to the given expression:

$\prod_{i=1}^{k}(i^4+4)\\=\prod_{i=1}^{k}[(i+1)^2+1][(i-1)^2+1]$

For $k\geqslant3$, there will be $k-2$ squares in the middle of the expansion. So the expressions unknown to be perfect squares are the two terms of both ends:

i.e. $[(1-1)^2+1][(2-1)^2+1] \\ [(k-1+1)^2+1][(k+1)^2+1]\\=2(k^2+1)(k^2+2k+2)$

Comment: Please tell me if anything is wrong/misunderstanding in my solution/proof, thanks, I can explain anything in my proof

Comment: Isn't $6\cdot 10\cdot 15$ a perfect square without any pair of factors multiplying to the third?  How does that mesh with how you've solved for $k$? (Even when one factor is prime, you would seem to need the other two factors to be square-free)

Comment: The initial claim that $ab=n^2$ implies that $a,b$ are themselves perfect squares does not hold: $2\cdot 8=4^2$. However, you can fix this noticing that $\gcd(k^2+1, k^2+2k+2)\mid 5$.

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot that the factors could be distributed between the multipliers, let me think about it and see if I come up with an edit

Comment: I don't see a way to prove $gcd(^2+1,^2+2+2)∣5$ although I noticed that, but I found that if $f(k)=k^2+1$ then $f(k+1)=k^2+2k+2$, is this info useful to prove the gcd observation?

Comment: If you do Euclid's algorithm on $k^2+1$ and $k^2+2k+2$, I think you come down to $5$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I believe the solution combined with @Dr.Mathva's argument works indeed!

Comment: @Dr.Mathva can you clarify what happens next? thanks

Comment: Why can’t it be $2(5a^2)(10b^2)$? Seems like that might give infinite possibilities.

Comment: To elaborate, knowing the gcd is 1 or 5 isn’t sufficient. Your cases are still too restrictive. If they have a common factor of 5, then one could be 5 times a square, and the other could be 10 times a square. There are infinitely many solutions to $5a^2=k^2+1$ from Pell (and same for 10).  It seems hard to show that all of the solutions of Pell for coefficient 5 that are one away from the coefficient 10 ones are trivial.